# Anatomically Correct Series

Tags: discussion, reference

**This Query is part of the Worldbuilding [Resources Article](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources).**

---

As you all know there is a series of questions that have been asked to create fictional creatures in a realistic evolutionary way.

And below is a summarized list of all of the questions in order of post, so that a link to this meta post should be enough for future questions.

-

*Edit*

Due to a large amount of low quality question using this series' formula, user JBH has suggested adding specifications to the core idea of the series. Below are the most recent rendition of the rules as of April 27 2018. If a question has used the title Anatomically Correct and you feel it's poorly executed, please link to this post.

The *Anatomically Correct* (AC) series of questions are a popular tradition on Worldbuilding.SE.  Their purpose is to invite site participants to consider how to describe fictional or mythological creatures from an evolutionary context with as much biological and behavioral realism as possible.

- In keeping with the Stack's general rule of not fielding questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds, the ACS is now limited to questions about documented myths and legends of Humanity and creatures thoroughly designed (other than lacking anatomical fulfillment) for a fictional world of the OP's own creation. ([Source](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7843/40609))

It is the responsibility of the questioner to provide sufficient detail to specifically identify the creature in question.

- Generalizations such as "Elves as commonly found in fantasy stories" or "vampires" (without further clarification) are unacceptable and grounds for closing the question as "Unclear what you're asking."
- Links to specific examples of the creature in question are encouraged, but may not be used alone.  A specific description of the creature is **required** or the question will again be closed as "Unclear what you're asking."  An ambiguous or insufficient description may result in closure due to the question becoming "Primarily opinion-based."
- Images of the creature are always appreciated.  If possible, reduce large images to a width of 450 pixels and link the image to a larger version.  As with links, images may not be used alone.  A specific description is required to avoid closure.
- Creature descriptions must include important behavioral attributes and a clear physical description.  It is the questioner's responsibility to invent the creature and the privilege of participants to explain how that invention could be manifest with evolutionary believability.  To coin a phrase, We're willing to help, but we will not invent the creature and summon it into this world for you.
- This question writing guide was developed long after the first AC question was asked.  While we encourage questioners to review earlier AC questions to better understand how to meet these requirements, the fact that some previously asked questions do not meet these expectations may not be used to justify a poor question.

The best answer is expected to be the one that provides the greatest detail, the greatest creativity, and the greatest capacity for suspension of disbelief.

-

*If you have come to comment on a recent Anatomically Correct post that needs to be added, please post that on the community answer, or I will not see it. Also, the question cannot have been closed within a week of posting because of being off-topic or a duplicate.*

Comment: Er...why "*anatomically*" correct? Aren't these just "scientifically correct"? "Anatomically" doesn't mean "evolutionarily", and "anatomically correct" typically means "including genitalia, nipples, etc." (E.g. there's a line in *Batman & Robin* making light of the infamous "bat-nipples" on the costumes in that movie: "an anatomically  correct rubber suit puts fire in a girl's...lips.")

Comment: ...and if you haven't seen that film but have heard how terrible it is, and you've wondered if it can possibly be as bad as people say, that line should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: @KyleStrand: "anatomically correct" does *usually* refer to sex organs, but can also refer to any other part normally depicted in an unrealistic manner. For example, typing "anatomically correct" in Google gives me "... heart" as the fourth suggestion. ("... baby dolls" is the first suggestion, and creepy images related to that search show up as you're typing. You might not want to try this at home.)

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson We're just going to have to agree to vehemently disagree on that, I guess. (Though the "mostly asexual" part simply baffles me.)

Comment: @MichaelS Good point. Even so, that still doesn't really match the intended meaning here!

Comment: @KyleStrand actually it is the intended meaning

Comment: That response doesn't actually make much sense. Your question indicates that what you *mean* is "realistic evolutionary" creatures, but that is *not* what "anatomically correct" means. "Anatomically correct" does not seem to mean what you think it means.

Comment: @KyleStrand anatomically correct means one of two things; (1) referring to correctly sexual organs in dolls OR (2) a part of a creature correctly placed and existing. These questions use the second meaning.

Comment: But you're not talking about "a part of" a creature. You're talking about the *entire creature* designed in such a way as to conform to all kinds of scientific principles, including *but not limited too* anatomy.

Comment: @KyleStrand good point, but I am not going to change it, so either be angry over a slight term that doesn't matter, or accept it. Your choice, I am not arguing this anymore.

Comment: I'm not angry, I'm just trying to help you use a correct term (I even suggested an obvious one, "scientifically correct") instead of a silly and incorrect one. Clearly you're not open to suggestions, which I suppose is fine.

Comment: @KyleStrand it's not that I'm not open, it's that I don't want to spend  hour replacing the links and titles. I am a busy guy and I don't care enough about some title to change it

Comment: Er... same difference. If you're not willing to change the phrase, then by definition you're not open to change suggestions. But I thought you were not going to argue the point any more? In any case, if the time required to make the change is the only thing holding you back from doing so, you could ask for help. Suggested edits to your question & answer here on meta aren't permitted, though, so you'd have to change these yourself.

Comment: why not just tag them as [tag:anatomically-correct]? It's the sort of thing that seems to come up enough--to a lurker like me--that it wouldn't be crazy to have a tag for it.

Comment: @KyleStrand Or "a creature with all its parts anatomically correct".

Comment: @tepples thats exactly what I mean.

Comment: That whole series irks me because the anatomy of a species is directly shaped by the species itself. So for instance "Anatomically correct human" means "A human that has all their organs, limbs and other bodily structures at pretty much the same lengths, widths and proportions as humans in general". Now translate that to every other species in this series. How would we know if one particular unicorn is "anatomically correct"? By comparing him to every other unicorn and see if he matches. Right.... so where are all our other unicorns to compare with? Uhm...

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors believe me, I am aware of the problems with the title. Keep in mind that it is just a catchy title.

Comment: Lol @ “busy guy”

Comment: @NuWin what do you mean?

Comment: @TrEs-2b, Given the recent difficulties with the OP of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110556/anatomically-correct-demons), would you object if opened an "answer" to this question with a brief listing of expectations that, once reviewed by the community and approved by you, would be edited into your question, above, to serve as basic guidance for both OPs and VTCers?  I suspect a short paragraph and a few bullet points would go a long way, and it would give us a clear link to direct OPs to about the entire tradition.

Comment: @JBH absolutely, I may not be active that much, but I'll help what I can. Any edits you currently have in mind?

Comment: Thanks!  I decided this might actually be easier as its own post, which would result in an edit to this question.  You can see my first effort [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/proposed-addition-to-anatomically-correct-to-establish-q-quality-expectations).  It wasn't quite as concise as I'd hoped.

Comment: @JBH great! I definitely agree that this question needs editing, just let me know when you have an edit in mind and I'll be more than happy to put it in.

Comment: you forgot about https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110970/anatomically-correct-oni

Comment: Can we add to these requirements what we ask for every other question on every SE site: **Show some effort**. I just voted to close this question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123281/anatomically-correct-xkcdius-lethalissimus because it asks *us* to do all the work.

Comment: It might be helpful for @JBH in particular to note in the main question perhaps what he considers "a very good AC query", "an okay AC query" and "a really inadequate AC query". At this point in time there something like 40 queries and I for one don't really know which of them is good or not!

Comment: @elemtilas, pointing fingers has consequences... especially if people don't agree with me.  I'm not even sure asking the community to vote on the best/worst of the series wouldn't violate the new code of conduct.  I feel your pain, but with community input, I made the criteria TrEs-2b added to the post as specific as I could.

Comment: Well, of course. But we "point fingers" here every day! That's what SE is all about, put bluntly: point out the best, downvote the rest! And put on hold whatever's left over!

Comment: Some  proposed changes to these criteria: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/change-proposal-for-anatomically-correct-series-criteria

Answer (score 46, accepted):

+The questions of the series are listed below in order of oldest to newest.

1. [Anatomically Correct Griffin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25281/anatomically-correct-griffins) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
2. [Anatomically Correct Angels](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25466/anatomically-correct-angels) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
3. [Anatomically Correct Nuckelavee](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25579/anatomically-correct-nuckelavee) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
4. [Anatomically Correct God](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25899/anatomically-correct-gods) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
5. [Anatomically Correct Werewolves](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/anatomically-correct-werewolves) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
6. [Anatomically Correct Pheonix](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28458/anatomically-correct-phoenix) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
7. [Anatomically Correct Cyclops](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30163/anatomically-accurate-cyclops) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
8. [Anatomically Correct 4-Legged Sapient Creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/realistic-4-legged-sapient-creatures-centaurs-etc) asked by [Crissov](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11787/crissov)
9. [Anatomically Correct Golem](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30771/anatomically-correct-golem) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
10. [Anatomically Correct Hecatoncheires](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31029/anatomically-correct-hecatoncheires) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
11. [Anatomically Correct Elemental](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/anatomically-correct-elemental) Asked by [Andyd273](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6751/andyd273)
12. [Anatomically Correct Nanaue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/anatomically-correct-land-shark) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
13. [Anatomically Correct Medusa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/anatomically-correct-medusa) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
14. [Anatomically Correct Hippocampus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34235/anatomically-correct-hippocampus) Asked by [Hanko Tanks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15131/hanko-tanks)
15. [Anatomically Correct Bio-fabricators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35835/anatomically-correct-bio-fabricator) Asked by [Donald hobson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17931/donald-hobson)
16. [Anatomically Correct Harpy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36722/anatomically-correct-harpy) Asked by [Caleb Woodman](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/14789/caleb-woodman)
17. [Anatomically Correct Jackalope](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38435/anatomically-correct-jackalope) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
18. [Anatomically Correct Xenomorph](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40985/anatomically-correct-xenomorph) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
19. [Anatomically Correct Hydra](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42017/anatomically-correct-hydra) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
20. [Anatomically Correct Naga](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44703/anatomically-correct-naga) Asked by [Jackwise](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19006/jackwise)
21. [Anatomically Correct Unicorn](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46099/anatomically-correct-unicorn) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
22. [Anatomically Correct King Kong](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46664/anatomically-correct-king-kong) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
23. [Anatomically Correct Khajiit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48778/anatomically-correct-khajiit) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
24. [Anatomically Correct Gnolls](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/anatomically-correct-gnolls) asked by [Shalvenay](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3097/shalvenay)
25. [Anatomically Correct Pixie](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48874/anatomically-correct-pixie) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
26. [Anatomically Correct Argonian](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48894/anatomically-correct-argonian) asked by [fi12](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17179/fi12)
27. [Anatomically Correct Sleipnir](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48913/anatomically-correct-sleipnir-eight-legged-horse) asked by [Ghanima](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/401/ghanima)
28. [Anatomically Correct Graboid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48988/anatomically-correct-giant-carnivore-earth-worm-graboid) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
29. [Anatomically Correct Tomte](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51326/anatomically-correct-tomte) asked by [Grollo](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/20953/grollo)
30. [Anatomically Correct Boar Troll](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51563/help-me-evolve-a-boar-troll/51576#51576) asked by [cobaltduck](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10851/cobaltduck)
31. [Anatomically Correct Cerberus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51758/anatomically-correct-cerberus) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
32. [Anatomically Correct Giant](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/anatomically-correct-giants/) asked by [LCIII](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19372/lciii)
33. [Anatomically Correct Arachne](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51903/anatomically-correct-arachne) asked by [渡し守シャロン](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/24960/%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%97%E5%AE%88%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3)
34. [Anatomically Correct Murloc](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52440/anatomically-correct-murlocs) asked by  [Sky](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/22678/sky)
35. [Anatomically Correct Ent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52483/anatomically-correct-ent) asked by [渡し守シャロン](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/24960/%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%97%E5%AE%88%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3)
36. [Anatomically Correct Den Den Mushi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52890/anatomically-correct-den-den-mushi) asked by [Masclins](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9526/masclins)
37. [Anatomically Correct Spriggan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53664/anatomically-correct-spriggan) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
38. [Anatomically Correct Minotaur](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55104/anatomically-correct-minotaur) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
39. [Anatomically Correct Pegasus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55996/anatomically-correct-pegasus) asked by [Yacomini](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/26717/yacomini)
40. [Anatomically Correct Slenderman](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60104/anatomically-correct-slenderman) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
41. [Anatomically Correct Creeper](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60132/anatomically-correct-creeper) asked by [T3 H40](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13987/t3-h40)
42. [Anatomically Correct Mokèlé-mbèmbé](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62036/anatomically-correct-mok%C3%A8l%C3%A9-mb%C3%A8mb%C3%A9/62037) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
43. [Anatomically Correct Slimes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/67182/anatomically-correct-slimes) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
44. [Anatomically Correct Multi-armed Humanoids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74254/anatomically-correct-multiarmed-humanoids) asked by [MarqFJA87](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/34687/marqfja87)
45. [Anatomically Correct Huddle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85641/anatomically-correct-huddle) asked by [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
46. [Anatomically Correct Nachtkrapp](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88204/anatomically-correct-nachtkrapp) asked by [Secespitus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28789/secespitus)
47. [Anatomically Correct Scylla](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96301/anatomically-correct-scylla) asked by [Lot-Of-Malarkey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/43370/lot-of-malarkey)
48. [Anatomically Correct Chimera](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97127/anatomically-correct-chimera) asked by [Lot-Of-Malarkey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/43370/lot-of-malarkey)
49. [Anatomically Correct Ponies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98175/anatomically-correct-ponies) asked by [gaazkam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6846/gaazkam)
50. [Anatomically Correct Ahuizotl](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100126/anatomically-correct-ahuizotl) asked by [cowrie](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/45244/cowrie)
51. [Anatomically Correct Typhon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101491/anatomically-correct-typhon) asked by [The Great Duck](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/22334/the-great-duck)
52. [Anatomically Correct Chocobo](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/105601/anatomically-correct-chocobo) asked by [Jakob Lovern](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/44805/jakob-lovern)
53. [Anatomically Correct Kappa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108369/anatomically-correct-kappa) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
54. [Anatomically Correct Satyrs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108418/anatomically-correct-satyrs) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
55. [Anatomically Correct Vampires](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108805/anatomically-correct-vampires) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
56. [Anatomically Correct Akaname](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108838/anatomically-correct-akaname) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
57. [Anatomically Correct Trolls](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108866/anatomically-correct-trolls) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
58. [Anatomically Correct Ghouls](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108880/anatomically-correct-ghouls) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
59. [Anatomically Correct Penanggalan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108958/anatomically-correct-penanggalan) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
60. [Anatomically Correct Zerg Overlord](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110613/anatomically-correct-zerg-overlord) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
61. [Anatomically Correct Oni](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110970/anatomically-correct-oni) asked by [TGCF](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/47352/tgcf)
62. [Anatomically Correct Mandrake](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111757/anatomically-correct-mandrake) asked by [TGCF](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/47352/tgcf)
63. [Anatomically Correct Siren](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/anatomically-correct-siren) asked by [incognito](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52361/incognito)
64. [Anatomically Correct Zombie](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/119299/anatomically-correct-zombie) asked by [Magus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/53175/magus)
65. [Anatomically Correct Hypnotoad](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122584/anatomically-correct-hypnotoad) asked by [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
66. [Anatomically Correct "XKCDius lethalissimus"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/123281/30492) asked [by L.Dutch](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/30492/l-dutch)
67. [Anatomically Correct Sharknado Shark](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/125602/21222) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
68. [Anatomically Correct metalhead, part 1 - headbanging](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/130755/anatomically-correct-metalhead-part-1-headbanging)  asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
69. [Anatomically Correct Sea Boar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/130822/30492) asked [by L.Dutch](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/30492/l-dutch)
70. [Anatomically Correct metalhead, part 2 - physiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/130914/21222) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
71. [Anatomically Correct Panotti](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/131539/30492) asked [by L.Dutch](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/30492/l-dutch)
72. [Anatomically Correct Space Plankton](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/131838/anatomically-correct-space-plankton) asked by [kingledion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/23519/kingledion)
73. [Anatomically correct Pushmi-pullu from Dr. Dolittle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/138080/anatomically-correct-pushmi-pullu-from-dr-dolittle) asked by [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
74. [Anatomically Correct Strange Women In Ponds Distributing Swords](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/142529/anatomically-correct-strange-women-in-ponds-distributing-swords) asked by [nullpointer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/51814/nullpointer)
75. [Anatomically Correct Pikachu](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/142740/anatomically-correct-pikachu) asked by [tox123](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2053/tox123)
76. [Anatomically Correct Mesopelagic Aves](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/142680/59407) asked by [A Lambent Eye](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/59407/a-lambent-eye)
77. [Anatomically Correct Vampire Teeth; Location, location, location](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/138669/anatomically-correct-vampire-teeth-location-location-location) asked by [Artsoccer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/50310/artsoccer)
78. [Anatomically Correct Huldra](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143635/anatomically-correct-huldra) asked by [Pleiades](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21733/pleiades)
79. [Anatomically Correct Carnivorous Tree](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/146798/59407) asked by [A Lambent Eye](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/59407/a-lambent-eye)
80. [Anatomically Correct Pinocchio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/146945/59407) asked by [A Lambent Eye](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/59407/a-lambent-eye)
81. [Anatomically Correct Swarm of Rodents](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148115/anatomically-correct-swarm-of-rodents) asked by [Liam Morris](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/62187/liam-morris?tab=profile)
82. [Anatomically Correct *Stranger Things* Mindflayer's Monster](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/151650/anatomically-correct-stranger-things-mindflayers-monster) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
83. [Anatomically Correct *Monsters, Incorporated*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/anatomically-correct-monsters-incorporated) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
84. [Anatomically Correct Hunter from *Needle*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152736/anatomically-correct-hunter-from-needle) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
85. [Anatomically Correct Slinky Worm](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152815/anatomically-correct-slinky-worm) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
86. [Anatomically Modular Body Plan Animals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152820/anatomically-correct-modular-body-plan-animals) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
87. [Anatomically Correct Whomping Willow](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/153662/anatomically-correct-whomping-willow) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
88. [Anatomically Correct Dreel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/154343/anatomically-correct-dreel) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
89. [Anatomically Correct Diegetic Singing Princess](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158347/anatomically-correct-diegetic-singing-princess) asked by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan)
90. [Anatomically Correct Dancing Brooms](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158643/anatomically-correct-dancing-brooms) asked by [overlord](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/68902/overlord)
91. [Anatomically Correct Color-Adjustable Eye](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158960/anatomically-correct-color-adjustable-eye) asked by [overlord](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/68902/overlord)
92. [Anatomically Correct Propellers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159150/anatomically-correct-propellers) asked by [overlord](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/68902/overlord)
93. [Anatomically Correct Ettin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/160771/anatomically-correct-ettin) asked by [Richard Lindahl](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/66420/richard-lindahl)
94. [Anatomically Correct Jaculus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161589/an-anatomically-correct-jaculus) asked by [Blueblood](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/70496/blueblood)
95. [Anatomically Correct Diggy Diggy Dwarfs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/anatomically-correct-diggy-diggy-dwarfs) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
96. [Anatomically Correct Succubus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/120804/anatomically-correct-succubus) asked by [Seraph Myrmidon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/31928/seraph-myrmidon)
97. [Anatomically Correct Triskelion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/129380/anatomically-correct-triskelion) asked by [elemtilas](https://stackexchange.com/users/10691130/elemtilas)
98. [Anatomically Correct Sonic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167550/anatomically-correct-sonic) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
99. [Anatomically Correct Yoshi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167654/anatomically-correct-yoshi) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
100. [Anatomically Correct Gigantes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167893/anatomically-) asked by [Richard Lindahl](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/66420/richard-lindahl)
101. [Anatomically Correct Sphinx](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167917/anatomically-correct-sphinx) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
102. [Anatomically Correct Catgirls](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167948/anatomically-correct-catgirls) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
103. [Anatomically Correct Leviathan (Intelligent Design)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167986/anatomically-correct-leviathan-intelligent-design) asked by [SE is too politically correct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/70058/se-is-too-politically-correct)]
104. [Anatomically Correct Grootslang](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169037/anatomically-correct-grootslang) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
105. [Anatomically Correct Kitsune](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169146/anatomically-correct-kitsune) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
106. [Anatomically Correct Loch Ness Monster](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169327/anatomically-correct-loch-ness-monster) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
107. [Anatomically Correct Manticore](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169404/anatomically-correct-manticore) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
108. [Anatomically Correct Frieza](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169330/anatomically-correct-frieza) asked by [Pierre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72048/pierre)
109. [Anatomically Correct Ammit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169761/anatomically-correct-ammit) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
110. [Anatomically Correct Yara Ma Yha Who](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/170114/anatomically-correct-yara-ma-yha-who) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
111. [Anatomically Correct Cockatrice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168362/anatomically-correct-cockatrice) asked by [RotNDecay](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/70683/rotndecay)
112. [Anatomically Correct Vanara](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/170141/anatomically-correct-vanara) asked by [TGCF](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/47352/tgcf)
113. [Anatomically Correct Kemonomimis](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/117923/anatomically-correct-kemonomimis) asked by [Mindwin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/353/mindwin)
114. [Anatomically Correct Isitoq](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143436/anatomically-correct-isitoq) asked by [SealBoi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49209/sealboi)
115. [Anatomically Correct Asari](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112387/anatomically-correct-asari) asked by [Preg-Fan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/46520/preg-fan)
116. [Anatomically Correct Shrek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/173307/anatomically-correct-shrek) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
117. [Anatomically Correct Super-Intelligent Shade of Blue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/173735/anatomically-correct-super-intelligent-shade-of-blue) asked by [KeizerHarm](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/51138/keizerharm)
118. [Anatomically correct bulborb](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110859/anatomically-correct-bulborb?rq=1) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
119. [Anatomically Correct Snallygaster](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122477/anatomically-correct-snallygaster?rq=1) asked by [Dabantam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48815/dabantam)
120. [Anatomically Correct Giant Seahorses](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/174311/anatomically-correct-giant-seahorses) asked by [Richard Lindahl](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/66420/richard-lindahl)
121. [Anatomically Correct Glebsig](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/181441/anatomically-correct-glebsig) asked by [Galactic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/181441/anatomically-correct-glebsig)
122. [Anatomically Correct Sentient Skeletons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/188632/anatomically-correct-sentient-skeletons) asked by [icewar1908](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72193/icewar1908?tab=profile)
123. [Anatomically Correct Night Land Monsters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227926/anatomically-correct-night-land-monsters) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
124. [Anatomically Correct Moonstrider](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/230011/anatomically-correct-moonstrider) asked by [JohnWDailey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10274/johnwdailey)
125. [Anatomically Correct Rull](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/230035/anatomically-correct-rull) asked by [Logan R. Kearsley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2800/logan-r-kearsley?tab=profile)
126. [Anatomically Correct Mummy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/232391/anatomically-correct-mummy) asked by [SquidKid999](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/80733/squidkid999)
127. [Anatomically Correct Elves](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/232104/anatomically-correct-elves) asked by [ITM_Coder](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/96931/itm-coder)
128. [Anatomically Correct Asian Dragons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/231950/anatomically-correct-asian-dragons) asked by [ITM_Coder](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/96931/itm-coder)
129. [Anatomically Correct Seas Serpents](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/232226/anatomically-correct-sea-serpents) asked by [ITM Coder](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/96931/itm-coder)

---

Comment: Have centaurs been made?

Comment: Does [Anatomically Correct Weebles](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1241/601) count?

Comment: @DamianYerrick if the title was edited, yeah

Comment: These are not in order of newest to oldest; they are in order of oldest to newest, except for the first six, which are scrambled (the correct order is 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6).  You don't need to follow all the links; just remember that question numbers are assigned sequentially, so sorting by question number is equivalent to sorting chronologically. Also, #8 is a link to an answer.

Comment: @PeregrineRook fixed, thank you

Comment: Can we alphabetize this list so it's easier to use as a reference?

Comment: @Nolo no, not because I don't want to (I don't) but also because that would mean complete re-editing every time a new one is asked and order of asking is good enough

Comment: @TrEs-2b Are you _sure_? :D  I made a little program to make it easy if you change your mind. https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/sort-linked-bullet-numbered-markdown-list/5422128070459392. :)

Comment: @Nolo That link is good, I might do it when I get the time.

Comment: I'll make it friendlier so you can just paste and push the button. I put that link up here when I get home.

Comment: I kindof like having it in historical order.  Maybe a second answer, alphabetized?  It'd mean updating two answers each time, but it's not like that's a very frequent occurrence, and this metaquestion will already be being bumped.

Comment: @Bobson sounds like a good idea! I have to go offline for a while, but if you or Nolo want to do it, sounds great!

Comment: @Bobson Done and done.

Comment: @TrEs-2b Just for your own info, see my new answer below.  Only I can edit the current program, i.e. keep it's record of the entries up to date, but anyone else can make a spin-off and have their own version if I drop off the face for any reason.  Numbering can be pasted or ignored (it is cleaned from the entry text anyway when sorting).  The answer does not disturb the linkages/enumeration in the original answer and the program also leaves those intact.  So three step update, paste the links below, paste the entries to the program, sort, paste the list over the one below.

Comment: How do new entries get added? Because I made [Anatomically correct mutliarmed humanoids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74254/anatomically-correct-multiarmed-humanoids) just the other day.

Comment: @MarqFJA87 Its a community answer, most people just add theirs in the appropriate area. I usually do it, but I haven't been online for a while, so I must have missed it. I'll do it now.

Comment: So my inability to edit the post (to add my entry) is normal?

Comment: @MarqFJA87 it has to do with your low reputation

Comment: I've just posted [Anatomically Correct Centaur](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/75966/anatomically-correct-centaur), but apparently do not have enough reputation to edit the wiki answer here. So... help?

Comment: @SomeoneElse37 That question has been asked multiple times before, [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/realistic-4-legged-sapient-creatures-centaurs-etc) and [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/realistic-4-legged-sapient-creatures-centaurs-etc) and thus, does not warrant a place on the list. Sorry though.

Comment: you need https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110970/anatomically-correct-oni

Comment: Made another one: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111757/anatomically-correct-mandrake?noredirect=1#comment341331_111757

Comment: Can someone do an anatomically correct Satan to go with Santa?

Comment: Another good one: Gremlins/Mogwai explaining the rules and the mammalian vs reptilian differences.

Comment: @Secespitus I'll add it, but keep in mind that as the answer is a community answer, you are free to add it as well

Comment: how do i add https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167550/anatomically-correct-sonic

Comment: Please just delete this entire series of close it

Comment: Why? It seems fine to me

Comment: It suddenly occured to me there no question anywhere about anatomically correct Marsipulamis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami

Comment: .. my attempt was closed as a duplicate within editing time and will be deleted soon, so a link would not be usefull. The one referred to by the mod may be added ?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-science-of-the-marsupilami