# Is there room in WorldBuilding for asking about the feasibility of science fiction ideas, which don't relate to building worlds?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Is there room in WorldBuilding for asking about the feasibility of science fiction ideas, which don't relate to building worlds?

I mean, asking about the feasibility or slight possibility of genetical, biological, etc. advances in the future. Science fiction concepts related to genetics and such make questions that are "too broad" for the Biology SE community.

I have questions related to science fictions concepts that, if they weren't because they are very specific about "how to build a world", they would fit better on WorldBuilding than on Science Fiction and Fantasy SE (which are about already existing SF and fantasy stories) or Biology SE (which is for more narrow, real and not theorized biology concepts).

Comment: You're not required to be building a world but we are fundamentally a fiction and creativity site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

#### Help Center

To give a short excerpt from the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help), specifically [What topics can I ask about?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Emphasis mine):

- Creation of **elements of a world** (languages, **species**, buildings, etc.)
- How to achieve a **specified effect in a defined world, including** the use of **biology**, technology or magic, while maintaning in-universe consistency

These are just two lines from the site to show that we welcome questions that are not about creating a whole world, but about an element of a world. And biology is an element of a world. As long as your question is answerable in the usual Q&A-style of StackExchange and you show that you are trying to build your own "world" or creature or whatever with them, instead of asking a canonical question that would be better at SF.SE, you can ask about the topics you mentioned in your question.

#### Chat

If you want to talk about your theories in an open-ended brainstorming style I recommend the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor). There we often have longer open discussions about topics that would not be good for the Main Site. This is also a great place to start if you are thinking about writing a question and want to get a bit of feedback on what things you should keep in mind when writing the question.

#### Sandbox

We have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on the Meta Site. It is designed to help people who are not sure if their question is ready for the Main Site. If you have a draft you can post it there together with your intended title and the tags you want to use. People can give you feedback on that specific question and show you how to improve it.

You should wait at least 24 hours after posting a question there before it moving it to the Main Site to give users in different timezones a chance to have a look at it. People will comment and vote to show whether your question is ready for the Main Site or not.

#### Examples

The following are a few examples that I had in mind when reading your question to show that we welcome questions about existing "worlds", though they are not necessarily about genetics:

- [Can a sonic screwdriver open doors?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/79911/can-a-sonic-screwdriver-open-doors) (Doctor Who)
- [What's the most reasonable way to fit monsters in your pocket?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/47251/whats-the-most-reasonable-way-to-fit-monsters-in-your-pocket) (Pokemon)
- [Why fill a dungeon with puzzles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36446/why-fill-a-dungeon-with-puzzles) (Skyrim)
- [How to realistically create a bow that's also two one-handed swords?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73432/how-to-realistically-create-a-bow-thats-also-two-one-handed-swords) (RWBY)
- [Anatomically correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series) (Series of questions about anatomically correct creatures; often inspired by myths)

There are many, many more on our site. Browsing the [genetics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genetics) might give you an idea about this specific topic.

Answer (score -1):

Just an addition to Secespitus answer: "asking about the feasibility or slight possibility of genetical, biological, etc. advances in the future" actually **is** worldbuilding because such in formations / discoveries **are**, or at least could be, world-changing events.

Of course if all you would ask id biological advance that would make some illness more survivable, by one percentage point, or other minor thing, it wouldn't be world building. But such questions seem rare.