# Proposed addition to "Anatomically Correct" to establish Q quality expectations for the series

Tags: discussion, editing

With TrEs-2b's blessing, I propose the following be added to his Meta question, [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series?noredirect=1#comment17888_2797), for the purpose of helping OPs understand the minimum requirements for and expectations of a good Anatomically Correct question and providing guidelines for closure reviews.  Once community reviewed and approved by TrEs-2b, it will be added to the question and the question itself will serve as a common link for new AC posters.

*Proposed modifications would be best submitted as answers to this question to better allow the community to comment on and vote on the changes.  Comments to the question should only be used to request clarification of my intent, to express joy or disdain for the effort, or to participate in a comedic roast of my character.*

---

Version 0.1 last edited 26 Apr 2018

*This version has been edited into TrEs-2b's question since April 27, 2018.*

---

The *Anatomically Correct* (AC) series of questions are a popular tradition on Worldbuilding.SE.  Their purpose is to invite site participants to consider how to describe fictional or mythological creatures from an evolutionary context with as much biological and behavioral realism as possible.

It is the responsibility of the questioner to provide sufficient detail to specifically identify the creature in question.

- Generalizations such as "Elves as commonly found in fantasy stories" or "vampires" (without further clarification) are unacceptable and grounds for closing the question as "Unclear what you're asking."
- Links to specific examples of the creature in question are encouraged, but may not be used alone.  A specific description of the creature is **required** or the question will again be closed as "Unclear what you're asking."  An ambiguous or insufficient description may result in closure due to the question becoming "Primarily opinion-based."
- Images of the creature are always appreciated.  If possible, reduce large images to a width of 450 pixels and link the image to a larger version.  As with links, images may not be used alone.  A specific description is required to avoid closure.
- Creature descriptions should include important behavioral attributes and a clear physical description.  It is the questioner's responsibility to invent the creature and the privilege of participants to explain how that invention could be manifest with evolutionary believability.  To coin a phrase, We're willing to help, but we will not invent the creature and summon it into this world for you.
- This question writing guide was developed long after the first AC question was asked.  While we encourage questioners to review earlier AC questions to better understand how to meet these requirements, the fact that some previously asked questions do not meet these expectations may not be used to justify a poor question.

The best answer is expected to be the one that provides the greatest detail, the greatest creativity, and the greatest capacity for suspension of disbelief.

Comment: expression of joy :)