# We have the "dragons" tag, so do we really need "dragon-anatomy" too?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms, tags

The description of the "dragons" tag is quite general, and it would certainly seem to include questions about their anatomy:

"For questions involving dragons - generally large, reptilian, flying creatures famous in folklore and myths."

This being the case, I don't think there's a need for a separate "dragon-anatomy" tag.

We currently only have three questions with this tag, two of which have negative score. Only one of them is also tagged "dragons", so someone using that tag to search for dragon questions wouldn't find the other two.

(I submitted an edit to add that tag to one of them, btw.)

And for someone who's used four other tags when composing their post, it could be difficult to work out which one to use, since the five-tag limit stops them using both.

Comment: I've added tag-synonyms as it seems to be relevant, please revert if you feel it's right. Interestingly in the process of that edit I've discovered that there are the tags: [tag:tag] and [tag:tags] - seems a bit superfluous, separate question.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see the need for dragon-anatomy. If we have that, then we should also have cat-anatomy, dog-anatomy, [whatever animal]-anatomy.

The tag of the animal and the tag anatomy together reach their goal of framing the question, so no need for the specialized one.

Meanwhile I have merged the dragon-anatomy tag.

Answer (score 1):

I've also noticed the heavy influx of dragon-related questions lately. I agree that there is a degree of redundancy between these two tags, but since they are not perfect synonyms, they might not warrant being combined.

Plenty of questions pertain to dragons but don't involve their anatomy:

- [Dragon vs Antiaircraft Artillery](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21719/dragon-vs-antiaircraft-artillery)
- [Building a](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/building-a-dragon) (robotic) [dragon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/building-a-dragon)
- [Mythical dragon diet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/140819/mythical-dragon-diet)
- [How to take down a dragon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/78144/how-to-take-down-a-dragon)
- [How effective would Dragon-Dragoons be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10688/how-effective-would-dragon-dragoons-be)

I think the "dragon-anatomy" tag provides a necessary distinction that will help people design fictional creatures. That being said, "creature-design" + "dragons" would also work - it just takes up two tag slots.

One potential solution could be a meta post like the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series) for people looking for all our dragon-design resources. That would collect the information in one place without requiring a new tag.

Comment: I'm not saying the tags are synonymous. I'm saying that I think the "dragons" tag on its own is adequate to cover cases related to dragon anatomy.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I edited the first few sentences to clarify. We both agree they aren't synonymous - my reasoning in the top half of the answer is that therefore, combining them may lose information.

Comment: The dragon diet question should have anatomy tag, IMHO.