# Links not formatting properly when there are 9+ of them

Tags: bug

There is a question ([this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/183609/21222)) with some links that don't show well-formatted. They are all formatted using the same structure:

```
 - [Seax][1] shark
 - [Kukri][2] shark
 - [Bayonet][3] shark
 - [Karambit][4] shark
 - [Rampuri][5] shark
 - [Shiv][6] shark
 - [Balisong][7] shark
 - [Bowie][8] shark
 - [Machete][9] shark
 - [Athame][10] shark
 - [Kilaya][11] shark
 - [Kirpan][12] shark
 - [Kris][13] shark
 - [Puukko][14] shark
```

All the links are valid. But they show up as per the screenshot below. Notice that beginning on the 9th link, it starts showing the raw Markdown instead of formatted links:

> [image: A screenshot of what the list above looks like on Chrome]

I am using Chrome and that happens both on desktop and mobile. I don't think it's browser related, though.

For comparison, [our list for the anatomically correct series questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2798/21222) does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by link number 8:

```
[8]: https://media.knivesandtools.com/Exact1200x800/140088/bo121547$01-boker.jpg
```

To be precise, the `$` sign is throwing off the Markdown parser and/or the MathJax renderer. If you replace it by `%24`, the [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) of the dollar sign, all links will work again. Note that link number 14 has the same problem.